# What is the most efficient way to convert an integer to the fractional part of a number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, integer, decimal, mantissa

I want to convert an integer to the fractional part of a number using javascript.

For example:

- 10030 -> 0.10030
- 123 -> 0.123

I've come up with two ways of doing this:

```
var convertIntegerPartToFractionalPart1 = function(integerPart) {
    var fractionalPart = integerPart;

    while(fractionalPart > 1) {
        fractionalPart = fractionalPart / 10;
    }
    return fractionalPart;
};

var convertIntegerPartToFractionalPart2 = function(integerPart) {
    return parseFloat('.' + integerPart);
};
```

convertIntegerPartToFractionalPart1 does not produce 100% accurate results, for example 132232 is converted to 0.13223200000000002. However convertIntegerPartToFractionalPart1 is more than twice as fast as  convertIntegerPartToFractionalPart2 under node.js on my MacBook Pro. (1000000 runs of convertIntegerPartToFractionalPart1 took 46ms, 1000000 runs of convertIntegerPartToFractionalPart2 took 96ms)

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The observation in method 1 would be clear upon reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse320/Documents/FloatingPoint.pdf)

Comment: You could do something like: `factionalPart = integerPart / (10 ^ ceil(log10(integerPart)))` [note this is pseudocode since you'd have to do your own log10 function based upon natural log in javascrit and use `Math.` for lib calls]. I suspect in the end, this will not be as good as your option 1. So my vote would be option 1 if you care more about time, and option 2 if you care about the result being perfect. :)

Comment: @mbratch doing it that way helps for some larger integers, but there'll always be problems (as devnull points out)

Comment: @Pointy, Yes I agree. I said in my comment it may not, in the end, be any better than option 1 (paraphrasing).

Comment: Your second method (if your original number is always an integer) would be most accurate (no floating point precision errors to deal with), however you'd need to test for decimal places in the parameter, that it's of type `Number` and that it isn't `Infinity` or `NaN`.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I can't make @mbratch suggestion work   `var convertIntegerPartToFractionalPartMbratch = function(integerPart) {
    return integerPart / (10 ^ Math.floor(1 + log10(integerPart)))
};

var log10 = function(number) {
    return Math.log(number) / Math.log(10);
};´

Comment: @alexbirkett check my answer; it's what he suggests basically.

Comment: @alexbirkett ..i think my answer will satisfy you. Have a look.

Comment: check my jsfiddle demo link also. here is a working sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first didn't want to answer, as Pointys solution seems far more elegant.

But after doing a [Jsperf](http://jsperf.com/cast-vs-math-int-to-frac) it turned out the Math solution was about 70% slower for me on chrome.

```
function cnvrt3 (n) {
  return n / Math.pow(10,(""+n).length)
}
cnvrt3(132232)//0.132232
```

So heres the same using casting to determine the power of ten

*Note due to the [floating point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) precision 0.132232 is not really `0.132232`. Though most likely the value you are looking for*

Comment: This is fastest of all 1000000 runs 21ms!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function cvt3(n) {
  return n / Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log(n)/Math.LN10));
}
```

It's still going to be possible that the result will not be exact, due to the nature of binary floating point (I think). But doing just one division might help. For smaller numbers your iteration might be just as good, and faster.

```
console.log( cvt3(132232) ); // 0.132232
```

*edit* the version by Mr. Monosodium Glutamate is faster!

Comment: You should always be dividing by an integer, so I don't think that it would be a signficant issue.  Usually, you only really see issues where floating point numbers are divided or multiplied numerous times, so (for the most part) this should not be an issue.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy and yet the iterative divide-by-10 method introduces an artifact.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy ... but maybe that's because 10 is being divided into a non-integer.

Comment: And it's done multiple times. After the first time, it's a floating point divide. So I think the pow10 method may be better in that regard. It eliminates the iterated variances.

Comment: ... and I forget the fundamental part of how numbers are represented in JavaScript.  Indeed this is the case over large numbers of divisions - once again I'd prove to be wrong.  `Math.log(10)/Math.log(2); // 3.3219280948873626`

Comment: It is a marginally faster, a million runs of cvt3(132232) take 41ms.

Answer (score 0):

You won't maintain **numbers** with trailing zeroes, as in your example:

```
10030 ->0.10030
```

but you can prepend a dot in front of a string:

```
'.'+String(10030)-> '.10030'
```

Comment: wouldn't '+("."+10030)' be sufficient ?

Answer (score 0):

> Here is best approach to so this :

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ew978/)

```
    function ab() {
        var a = 566123;

        var len = a.toString().length;
        var decimalPoints = 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            decimalPoints = decimalPoints * 10;
        }

        var number = parseInt(a) / decimalPoints;
        alert(number);
    }
```

Comment: 1000000 runs of this solution takes 39ms compared to 21ms for @C5H8NNaO4 solution under Node on my MacBook Pro

Comment: Not really sure why you need parseInt(a), a is already a number, right?

Comment: And the for loop could be replaced with Math.pow(10, len)

Comment: But even this 'function ab(n) {
    var len = n.toString().length;

    return n / Math.pow(10, len);
}' takes 28 ms (100000 rounds on my macbook pro)